# Phonegap camera API (iOS) submits FORM?

Tags: javascript, ios, forms, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm putting a camera button in a form so you can take the photo and it'll save the URI to a localStorage variable. The problem is every time the camera launches, the form is submitted without me hitting the submit button so the URI is never stored. I need it not to trigger submitForm(). Any insights?

Oh, the app is using jquerymobile.

html form

> ```
>             <form method="post" onsubmit="return submitForm()" id="myForm" data-ajax="false">
>                 <lable for="title" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Title</lable><input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"><br>
>                 <button onclick="capturePhoto()">Camera</button><br>
>                 <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description">
>                 <input type="submit" value="submit">
>             </form>
> ```

js

> function submitForm() {
>                   db.transaction(insertDB, errorCB);
>                   $.mobile.changePage( "#page2", { reverse: false, transition: "slide" } );
>                   return false;
>   }
>
> function capturePhoto() {
>               // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
>               navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
>   }

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I used the `<button>` tag for the Camera. This will trigger an onsubmit event. I used a regular `<a href>` in stead and that worked.